# Get list of index names matching pattern from elastic search - JAVA

Tags: java, list, elasticsearch

I have a list of indexes in elastic search as follow:

```
index1, index2, index3, test-index1, test-index2, test-index3
```

Now I want only those indexes that matches my pattern "test-*".

I can achieve the above result by following sense query:

```
GET test-*/_aliases
```

I want to achieve the same result from java code.

Answer (score 1):

The REST endpoint that responds to `/test-*/_aliases` does the following ([see here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/1452ab4b9f7fcd2b2699dc95fc64f03f1d97338f/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/admin/indices/RestGetAliasesAction.java)):

```
    GetAliasesResponse getAliasesResponse = client().admin().indices()
        .prepareGetAliases()
        .setIndices("test-*", "index-*").get();
```

Comment: can i have comma-separated pattern to get the indexes. For e.g: GET test-*,index-*/_aliases ???

Comment: I am using 1.7.4 elastic-search client library which does not support execute.

Comment: It is throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception

Comment: Can you update your question with the full stack trace please?

Comment: 9200 is the HTTP port (for any HTTP client) and 9300 is a TCP port (for the Transport client). So your ES actually has both ports open and that's normal

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Have found a temporary work around, i'm getting all the indices from es and filtering them on client side.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't make it work (i.e. what does "returning null values" mean).

Comment: What i mean to say is, i'm getting null response from the server, instead of getting expected response.

Comment: Yes, but that's really not clear why. and the workaround of getting all indices and doing the work on the client side is not ideal in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

ES version 8 update. ES has changed A LOT since 2016.

This doesn't appear to be how the `_aliases` endpoint works any more.

To get a list of indices matching a pattern, do this:

```
https://localhost:9200/_cat/indices/test-*
```

I don't know how the ES client in a given language would do that. Or what the point of it is: using `requests` works fine in Python, and `reqwests` in Rust. Seems to be something similar in Java.